# Excel - Remove Duplicates based off of text data in other column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: Link with example below]

I am trying to remove duplicate Item Numbers in column A, this is simple if the status in column C is also the same, like rows 1&2, and 6&7.  But if the duplicate item numbers have rows with "Active" and rows with "Inactive" in column C I want to keep one with "Active" and remove the "Inactive" duplicate. Then I can simply remove the duplicates after that. Basically if the item numbers have even one active row then I will know the item is active and the inactive rows are old SKUs.

Comment: Sort the columns, on A and C.  Then use Remove Duplicates on the three columns using only column A.  It will keep the first version which since it is sorted will be one with active if exists.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks - I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the formula:
*=COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,B1,$C$1:C1,C1)+IF(D1="Active",1,2)*
[image]

Filter the first Column = **2**